# Disable cleaning of container that run with --rm

Tags: docker

Is there a way to "disable" the --rm option for a specific running container?
I have a container running that might crash at some random point and I would like to debug the problem.
The problem is that the container was started as "docker run --rm", so it will be cleaned up / removed after crashing.
How can I get docker to ignore the --rm parameter for this already running container?

Answer (score 0):

That's not an option to [`docker update`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/), so you can't change it after the container has been created.

Only a very few things can be `docker update`d, generally only the resource constraints and restart policy.  For other settings you need to `docker rm` the container (in your case will happen automatically) and `docker run` a new container with the desired options.